# jqGrid: conditionally hide / show column content **per row**

Tags: struts2, jqgrid, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid, struts2-jquery-plugin

Is there *any* way to target a column in a jqGrid (in my case, Struts2-jQuery-Grid Plugin 3.7.0) on certain rows only ?

For example, I want to show the content of the 2nd column only if the 1th column value is ***Movie***:

```
 _______________________________________________________
|       COL 1       |               COL 2               |
|===================|===================================|
|   Movie           | bla bla yada yada                 |
|-------------------|-----------------------------------|
|   Song            |                                   |
|-------------------|-----------------------------------|
|   Clip            |                                   |
|-------------------|-----------------------------------|
|   Movie           | foo or bar that is the question...|
|-------------------|-----------------------------------|
|   Game            |                                   |
|___________________|___________________________________|
```

I've tried to use conditional OGNL expressions in `hidden` and `cssClass` fields of the [GridColumnTag](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridColumnTag), but immediately noticed they evaluate once against the whole column, not at every "iteration".

As a workaround, I can manually hide the columns in that rows with javascript after the grid is populated, but that is a hack, and I'm wondering if there is a clean solution to conditionally "do something" on a columns per-row.

NOTE: I can't simply erase the content from the source `List` (as it would be obvious) because COL 2 in my real case is a `Boolean`, represented as `checkbox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways how you can implement the requirement. One of the most easy is the setting of `color: transparent;` CSS on the cells which you need to hide. For example you define the CSS rule

```css
.hiddenCell { color: transparent; }
```

and you assign the class `hiddenCell` to specified cells of the "COL 2". You can use `cellattr` property of "COL 2" for it:

```js
cellattr: function (rowId, val, item) {
    if (item.sent) {
        return " class='hiddenCell'";
    }
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/transparentTextInColumn.htm) demonstrates the approach. Disadvantage of the approach - the hidden text still exist on HTML page and so one can examine it if required.

Another way is the usage of custom formatters. For example you can define the following `formatter` callback

```js
formatter: function (cellValue, options, item) {
    return item.sent ? "" : $.jgrid.htmlEncode(cellValue);
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/removeTextInColumn.htm) demonstrates the second approach. Disadvantage of the approach - it's a little difficult to combine usage of custom formatter with *another formatter* (like `formatter: "select"` in the example above). Nevertheless one can do it too:

```js
formatter: function (cellValue, options, item, action) {
    return item.sent ?
        "" :
        $.fn.fmatter.call(
            this,
            "select",
            cellValue,
            options,
            item,
            action);
}
```

like [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/removeTextInColumn_.htm).

If you loads the data from the server then probably the best choice would be to *modify* the input data (the input data for the column "COL 2") inside of `beforeProcessing` callback. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855764/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9722466/315935) for code examples.

Comment: Great answer. Regarding **Solution 1**, I don't think is possible in Struts2-jQuery-Grid (it does not have `cellattr` exposed); since I'm using `checkbox` formatter, I will create a custom one with another formatter, as in **Solution 2b**. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Two side effects, checkbox is not centered in the <td> anymore, and rows with even only one field empty (returned "" from the formatter) have an *higher* line-height, 33 instead of 24 (!).

Comment: Returning " " prevents the second one.

Comment: @AndreaLigios: You are welcome! I think that the usage of `"&nbsp;"` instead of `""` or `" "` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

For the records, the solution for the (fake) scenario described in the question (using *Struts2-jQuery-Grid* Plugin instead of the raw *jqGrid*) would be:

```jsp
<script>
   function conditionalFormatter(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
       return rowObject.type!="Movie" ? "&nbsp;" : $.jgrid.htmlEncode(cellValue);
   }
</script>

<s:url id="remoteurl" action="myStrutsAction" namespace="/myNamespace" />

<sjg:grid href="%{remoteurl}" dataType="json"  gridModel="gridModel" >
    <sjg:gridColumn title="Col 1" name="type" />
    <sjg:gridColumn title="Col 2" name="foo" formatter="conditionalFormatter" />
</sjg:grid>
```