# Edit multiple rows in Table Struts2

Tags: struts2, displaytag

I am displaying a list of data returned from database to JSP.
Now, this list has fields that are editable. And user can select more than 1 row to edit.

My requirement is to display the list, override the list(which has dropdown and checkbox fields that can be overridden by user) and then all of it to be saved to database.

I used displayTag to display the data, but now User editing few fields and populating that table to Action class part I am not able to get.

Can you give some suggestions?
May be other than displaytag also?

Comment: jqGrid, either native or from struts2-jquery-grid-plugin

Comment: Can we do it via Javascript?

Comment: jQuery is a Javascript library. jqGrid is based on jQuery. You *will have* to use Javascript, how much depends on you. Search on StackOverflow and Google for jqGrid examples, especially answers from [**Oleg**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg), like [**the one**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22386707/1654265) he gave me. Struts2 jQuery Grid Plugin wraps most of the javascript of the jqGrid into Struts tags, preventing you from doing it. Good luck ;)

Comment: May be you post the code what have you done so far. All these grids allows editing only one row.