# sjg:gridcolumn edit rule for decimal number

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="orderLowPrice" title="Oder Low price" sortable="false" editable="true" edittype="text"/>
```

The above has to be a 7,4 decimal number basically with 3 digit max number and 4 decimal places.

how to set this rule in the grid column?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the libraries loaded, but JavaScript has some basic numeric formatting in place.  use `toPrecision(7)` or `toFixed(4)` to obtain your desired results.

`toPrecision(7)` will only show 7 digits total (truncating if necessary)
`toFixed(4)` will only truncate the decimal to 4 digits.

I believe you can use formatter="formatNumber" in your column markup, and then the format function that it calls:

```xml
<sjg:gridColumn name="orderLowPrice" 
               title="Oder Low price" 
            sortable="false"        
            editable="true" 
            edittype="text" 
           formatter="formatNumber" />

...

<script>
    function formatNumber(number){
        return number.toFixed(4);
    }
</script>
```

you can also reference here for more formatting information: https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/FormatGrid

Comment: @user3761541 What do you mean with that didn't work ? Any error ? What have you tried ? BTW, related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22408093/1654265